# What does this notation denote?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does the following notation denote: $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \bigcap_{j\ge i}^\infty A_i$$

A. All elements that are in finitely many $A_i$;

B. All elements that are in infinitely many $A_i$;

C. All elements that are in all but infinite numbers of $A_i$;

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Well, can you rule out some of them? What are your thoughts?

Comment: None of A,B,C are correct as written.

Comment: Are you sure the question said "C. ... all but infinite numbers of $A_i$?

Comment: @vadim123, do you think it's truly $A_i$ (rather than $A_j$, like Assaf assumed) in the definition?

Comment: This question really makes no sense.  I assume it is from some text.  Could you include an image of the _entire_ question (not just the formula you originally included)?

Comment: The index $j$ is never used. Should $A_i$ be $A_j$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Corrected that.

Comment: @ARi: You should leave such corrections to the OP.

Comment: Whoops, thanks guys for catching my error.

Comment: @vadim123: No.  You matched the original image perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is meant for the edited question in which the "typo" was corrected. If it was in fact not a typo, then obviously this answer does not apply.

---

Personally, I find it helps to "unpack" expressions like this. Observe that the following are equivalent.

$$x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \bigcap_{j\geq i}^\infty A_j$$

$$(\exists i \in \mathbb{N})\;\; x \in \bigcap_{j\geq i}^\infty A_j$$

$$(\exists i \in \mathbb{N})(\forall j \geq i)\; x \in A_j$$

So basically, $x$ is an element of the expression under question iff there is a term $A_j$ such that $x$ is an element of $A_j,$ and remains an element thereafter.

The correct answer is therefore:

D. All the elements that belong to all but finitely many of the $A_j$'s.

Comment: You're assuming that $A_j$ and not $A_i$ is written in the post. But the truth is different. The OP posted an image which included this possible typo, which means that this is the original intent of the question. Now we need to wait and see if the OP's image contained a typo or not before we can answer that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. I assume that the question is about $\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty \bigcap_{j \geqslant i}^\infty A_j$. First try to give a description of the set $\bigcap_{j \geqslant i}^\infty A_j$ for a fixed $i$.

Comment: Note that the question states $A_i$ and not $A_j$. Probably a typo, but one can never know.